# Size image to container while maintaing aspect ratio in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a bunch of images of different (unknown) dimensions.

I want to drop these images into a div and have them automatically conform to the dimensions of the div, while maintaining their aspect ratio.

In other words, if the image is wider than high, the width will be 100%, and the height will scale accordingly.  If the image is higher than wide, the height will be 100%, and the width will scale accordingly.

Is there any way to do this in pure css?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the css properties [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width) and [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-height) on the image will get you where you need to be.

**Fiddle**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/sHAQ9/

**HTML**

```
<div>    
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000000/ffffff.png&text=tall%20image"/>
</div>
<div>    
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/ffffff.png&text=wide%20image"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;    
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
}
div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This works up until the image is 100% of its true size on one axis.  Is there a way to size it beyond 100%?

Comment: This is not working when I have increased the size of div. see [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sHAQ9/30/). Is there any solution to stretch it to fit to width or height.?

Answer (score 2):

I do this with my gallery setup:

```
.ScaledImg {
    max-width:100%:
    max-height:100%;
}
```

The img scales to fit the dimensions of its parent/container based on this, while maintaining its aspect ratio. I haven't tried this with anything other than imgs, but works well for me. No `width` or `height` declarations are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .fit_image img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    .fit_image {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="fit_image">
     <img src="/path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @iambriansreed fiddle,
Use zoom on the image when it's smaller than the container

```
div img {
    zoom: 10;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/vcapr0k8/